# Page not appearing in navigation bar

Tags: menus

Here is the site:
http://goo.gl/QgfSMq

I have a Testimonial page and a Blog page but they are not appearing in the navigation bar.

http:// progreenkleen.net/blog/
I have set this page to be the blog page

http://progreenkleen.net/testamonials/
(I know it's spelled wrong)

I have made sure that they pages are published, public, and I have looked in the Custom Menu but that does not seem to be operative. There are pages listed in the custom menu section, but I removed a couple of existing pages and they are still appearing in the navigation bar.

I was able to set a couple of the existing pages as Draft and they disappeared.

I have compared the pages I want to appear with existing ones and I don't see anything irregular.

I'm lost as to what to check next.

Comment: From where are you setting menu? Have you tried **Appearance > Menus**?

Comment: Yes I have tried to set the menu via Appearances > Menus (I called Custom Menus above).

As I mentioned, there is a menu in Appearances > Menus but it does not appear to be operative. When I add the pages I want they do not appear in the navigation menu. And when I delete one of the pages that was already there, the item does not disappear from the navigation menu. 

Obviously Appearances > Menus does not work, and I'm not sure why it's there (I did not create the site).

Comment: 1st, please share your [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) code from the theme. 2nd, see that is that checked something like: **Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu** in your menu in Appearance > Menus.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Appearance > Menus and add the page to the menu (Make sure you save the menu)

[image: Appearance > Menus]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the [Menus -> Manage Locations](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3aappearance-menus-maintain.png), it's probably the menu you adjusted is not the menu you display on your site. If you have 2 menus but only 1 theme location, that could happen.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This theme has a special built-in way of inserting items into the nav bar. The built-in menu handler then put the items into Appeareance > Menus.

I guess it's for people don't want to take the time to figure it out. It worked in the opposite direction for me.