# deleted menu still present

Tags: menus

I deleted a menu, but it still shows at the top of [my website](http://sec-2-sec.com) (About Us -to- Request Consulting Services).

The site is using AppThemes.com's JobRoller theme as a parent, and the Flux child theme.

There are no caching plugins installed.

When I change the theme, the front end changes immediately.

So why doesn't the menu change immediately after it is deleted?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131437/page-not-appearing-in-navigation-bar/)? It seems you have the same kind of problem.

Comment: Some themes use [Transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) in Menu pos. Better contact with the theme dev.

Comment: @1fixdotio: That question is about a menu *not* appearing.

Comment: Any idea what the down vote is for?  For someone's opinion?

Comment: I don't see a menu on this site, did you solve the problem?

Comment: According to @Steve the theme is falling back to wp_page_menu if there's no menu defined for that location. Instead of downvoting the question - #facepalm .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The theme displays pages in the primary menu location even when there is no Wordpress menu assigned to that location.

I changed the pages to Draft status to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your question is about the manually created menu, not about the automatically created list of pages.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote.  Your statement is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these things get messed up. If you have access to database, try to delete transient options (look for any keys that contains "transient" and/or your deleted menu name) from wp_options table

Comment: There were no keys with transient in them that related to the problem menu.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can happen because of 2 reasons. 
First of all because of Cache. of you are using a cache plugin to speedup your site this can happen, clear your cache and refresh your page.
Second it can be because of WordPress's transient API which some plugins or themes use to cache data in database with an expiration date. you can use a plugin called "Artiss Transient Cleaner" or search for other methods.